How to set website url with telegram bot?
I'm seeking a method to programmatically configure the website URL using an API. Currently, I've developed a bot and obtained its API token, which allows me to access other APIs seamlessly. However, when it comes to setting the redirect URL, the process involves navigating to Fatherbot and executing the command /setdomain, followed by selecting the bot and specifying the URL.
Is there a way to automate this process using an API? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that enables me to set the redirect URL directly through an API call, streamlining the configuration workflow.
